# Multiple Subscriptions Happening on Button Click

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component which contains a list of items, where, in each item, a button allows a user to delete said item.

Upon the clicking of the `delete` button, a modal is opened with a confirmation on whether or not they want to delete the item. When the `delete` button is clicked, the following function is fired:

```
public removeSite(site: site): void {
    this.deleteSiteModal.open(site);

    site.siteDeletion = true;

    this._subscriptions.push(this.deleteSiteModal.siteToDelete.subscribe((siteToDelete) => {
        if (siteToDelete) {
            this._subscriptions.push(this.myService.deleteSite(siteToDelete.guid).subscribe(sites => {
        }
    }));
}
```

What ends up happening though is that every time this button is clicked, there are multiple subscriptions that take place which result in multiple requests being sent out. An item will be deleted and then it will try to delete the same item again and fail because it is not found.

My colleague has mentioned that I should instead subscribe once, outside of my component, to `siteToDelete` and only perform an action when the button is clicked.

Any thoughts on this or ways to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Does `this.deleteSiteModal.siteToDelete` emit when the user confirms the delete? Why the truthy check on `siteToDelete`? Do you do something in the subscribe for `myService.deleteSite`?

Comment: Yes. Not entirely sure (this component has been modified by several developers). The rest of the logic for actually removing the site goes there but I just decided to keep it out at the moment (it's just a filter on an array).

Comment: Do you ever unsubscribe when the modal closes?

Comment: I unsubscribe in my `ngOnDestroy`

Comment: The ngOnDestroy of the parent component or the modal? If you aren't unsubscribing when your modal closes then your subscriptions will build up (+1 every time `removeSite` is called) and you will have an increasing number of calls to your delete api.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your colleague.  A component should not be worried about doing the actual deletion of sites.  A components job is to grab information from inputs and services to display to the user and to direct user input to outputs and services.  That being said, taking information from completed modals and passing them around is a bit of a grey area, I wouldn't dismiss it out of hand.  However, I think there may be two better options.

Either your modal component should call some site management service's delete method directly or some site management service should subscribe to `siteToDelete`.